# undefined working with Javascript -> Actionscript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

It must be late, but i'm not seeing the errors of my ways. i'm simply trying to call an AS3 fx from JS. Code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getFlashMovie(movieName) {   
      var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;   
      return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];  
    }
    getFlashMovie('myswf').playASound();
</script>

    <div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1" height="1" id="myswf" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="myswf.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myswf.swf" width="1" height="1">
                <param name="movie" value="myswf.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

calling the same method within AS3 plays the sound, so I know that the sound plays. The console gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'playASound' of undefined
```

Thanks!!

EDIT RE: PROGRESS...

This is where I'm at now, still having a null object issue:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = false;
    var attributes = {
       id: "sounds",
       name: "sounds"
    };
    var params = {
       wmode: "transparent",
       menu: "false", 
       allowScriptAccess: "always",
       play: "true"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("file.swf", "flash-sound", "10", "10", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="flash-sound"><!--<p>Alternative content</p>--></div>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById('sounds').playSound();
    });

      </script>
</body>
```

and the error is Cannot call method 'playSound' of null

Comment: Consider using `document.getElementById`: that `getFlashMovie` will only work in somebrowsers (IE and Opera?) AFAIK -- the problem is that it (`getFlashMovie`) *returns* undefined (because it is borked or the DOM is not yet loaded; that is, try to put the script in the "on load" event, or at least *after* the markup to create the object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the undefined because it can't find your swf in the DOM.

Try using this instead of that "getFlashMovie"-thing

```
document.getElementById('flashObj').playASound();
```

**Don't forget to set the id-attribute of your swf to "flashObj"**.

Also, I recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to embed your swf into your html:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("boot.swf", "flash", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "assets/swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

var flashvars = {lang: "<?php echo $lang ?>"};
var params = {allowFullScreen : false, allowScriptAccess: "always", bgcolor: "#FFFFFF", wmode: "transparent"};
var attributes = {id:"flashObj"};
```

Comment: I've edited the comment with some progress. still not working tho!

Comment: did you load jquery? Also, don't make your wmode transparent, unless you really have to.